# error Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-directive, angular13

I work on angular 13 application I face issue when declare variable of type model .

error Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

error happen when declare items variable for type model itemData as below :

```
items:ItemsData[]
```

model items data

```
export interface ItemsData {
    id:number;
    itemNameER:string;
    itemNameEN:string;
    description:string;
}
```

component.ts

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

 items:ItemsData[];
  
  constructor(private erpservice:ErpServiceService) { }

  
  retrieveAllItems(pageNumber: number = 0): void {
    this.erpservice.getAll(pageNumber)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
        this.items=data.items;
          console.log(data);
        });
  }

}
```

I need to recieve result returned from function `retrieveAllItems` on itemsData model i created but it give me error .

so How to solve issue and why this issue happen ?

**updated post**

i still have issue when get result of `retrieveAllItems` function on this line

```
this.items=data.items;
```

property items doesnot exist on type itemdata

so what i do to solve this issue ?

`console.log(data);` data returned as below :

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "itemNameEN": "pen"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "itemNameEN": "pencil"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "itemNameEN": "pen2"
        }
    ],
    "pager": {
        "numberOfPages": 1,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalRecords": 3
    }
}
```

service.ts

```
getAll(pageNumber: number): Observable<ItemsData> {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (pageNumber)
      params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

    let httpOptions = {
        params: params
    };
    return this.http.get<ItemsData>(baseUrl,httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: It looks like `data.items` which is assigned in `getAll(pageNumber)`, is not of type `ItemsData[]`. But to be sure I would have to see your `retrieveAllItems()`-method

Comment: The return-type of `getAll()` is wrong. `getAll()` does not return an observable of type `ItemsData`. Based on your json-data it returns an observable of an object which contains an `ItemsData`-array. In my answer I explained how you could solve this. Please tell me if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About your first issue**

It occurs because you have not initialized `items` with a value.

There are several options on how to solve the issue:

```
items: ItemsData[] = []; // Initialization with an empty array
```

```
items?: ItemsData[]; // Declaration as an optional variable
```

```
items!: ItemsData[]; // Declaration as non-nullable which basically corresponds to 'items: ItemsData[] = undefined'
```

---

**About your second issue**

According to your method signature `getAll()` returns `Observable<ItemsData>`, but this does not correspond to the json-response you showed me. It actually returns something like `Observable<DataWrapper>` and then you should define an **additional model** that looks like this:

```
export interface DataWrapper {
  items: ItemsData[];
}
```

Then the **service.ts** would look like this:

```
getAll(pageNumber: number): Observable<DataWrapper> {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (pageNumber)
      params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

    let httpOptions = {
        params: params
    };
    return this.http.get<DataWrapper>(baseUrl,httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: ok this is good but how to recieve  result of data data.items it still give issue on this.items=data.items;

Comment: What does the console-output look like when you do `console.log(data);`?

Comment: i get compile error so i can't run to see log text

Comment: i updated post with data returned

Comment: Please show also the code of  your service-method `getAll()`. This method is almost certainly the reason why you get a compile-time error.

Comment: i updated post with service get all function

Comment: OK, I extended my answer. Please try to introduce the interface `DataWrapper` (or you can give it any other name) as described in my answer.